# How can I assign a dedicated ip to a specific path on my server?

Tags: ip, lighttpd

I'm using Lighttpd and it works great.

I need to point the dedicated ip provided by my hosting service to a specific website on my VPS .

1)
If I browse to the dedicated ip, I currently get an error message "could not connect to ..".
Should I first enable on DNS settings.. or should I work on webserver configuration ?

2)
I've added these lines to lighttpd config file. Is that correct ? (XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX is the dedicated ip)

```
$SERVER["socket"] == "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80" {
  server.document-root = "/var/www/path/to/website "
}
```

**Update**

```
ping XXX.XXX.95.175
PING XXX.XXX.95.175 (109.72.95.175) 56(84) bytes of data.
From XXX.XXX.95.174 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From XXX.XXX.95.174 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From XXX.XXX.95.174 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Work on the configuration - DNS is irrelevant if you are using an IP address.  DNS looks up an IP address for a given a host name, In your case, you already know the IP address.

2) Looks fine.

I would imagine that you have problem with the IP address on the VPS rather than Lightttpd.  Check you Lighthttp logs to see if the requests are actually hitting it.

Comment: I've realized the Dedicated IP is actually enabled. I've updated my question with the results of a ping. The ip changes after a while... What should I deduce from these results ?

Comment: By the way, I've actually changed $SERVER to $HOST because I was getting an error